# The reason that inheritance is able to restrict mixin composition target

Tags: scala, inheritance, mixins, traits

I known using class inheritance on trait is able to constrain what the class it can mix with.
It's a well known method for adding restriction when mixin :

```
class Foo
trait FooTrait extends Foo
val pass = new Foo with FooTrait
class Bar
val error = new Bar with FooTrait //illegal inheritance: superclass Bar is not a subclass of the superclass Foo of the mixin trait FooTrait
```

or

```
abstract class Foo
trait FooTrait extends Foo
class Bar
val error = new Bar with FooTrait //illegal inheritance
```

> Is this just the special syntax for this purpose ?

I ask this because I can not figure out how to **explain this using concept of inheritance** .
In addition, I cannot explain the opposite outcome if you inherit trait instead of abstract class:

```
trait Foo
trait FooTrait extends Foo
class Bar
val pass = new Bar with FooTrait // no restriction!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key things to understand here are the following:

1. In Scala `traits` are mixed in, rather than inherited. And mixing in has important differences from inheritance.
2. When you mix in a trait, you implicitly inherit the `trait`'s super-class.

If your `trait` does not declare a super-class, it has the default superclass of `AnyRef`.

Now, if you did something like the following:

```
class Foo                  \\ 1 
trait FooTrait extends Foo \\ 2
class Bar extends FooTrait \\ 3
```

The third line would compile correctly. But when you do

```
val bar = new Bar with FooTrait
```

it fails to compile.

The reason is that when you use the latter form, you are implicitly creating a subclass of `Bar`. Let me try to make it a bit clearer. When you say `val bar = new Bar` the `bar` variable is not an instance of the class `Bar`. It is an instance of an anonymous subclass of `Bar`.

So, putting all of this together, when you do something like `val bar = new Bar with FooTrait`, what you are essentially trying is to create an anonymous class with two super-classes. The two super-classes being

1. `Bar` which you are explicitly inheriting from
2. `Foo` which you are inheriting via the `Footrait`

JVM doesn't allow inheriting from multiple classes, regardless of whether they are abstract or not. Inheriting from multiple interfaces is fine though. That's why your last example:

```
trait Foo
trait FooTrait extends Foo
class Bar
val pass = new Bar with FooTrait // no restriction!
```

compiles fine, because traits are equivalent of interfaces in Java.

Comment: Is this memory trick appropriate: "`Bar with FooTrait` is `Bar` with a mixin; `Bar extends FooTrait` inherits from `FooTrait` and thus from `Foo `"?

Comment: @SillyFreak I think both are mixins. The same thing is happening whether you use `new Bar with FooTrait` or `Bar extends FooTrait`. The only difference being that in the former case, an additional class, `Bar`, is being extended by an anonymous class, in addition to the `FooTrait` and consequently `Foo`.

Comment: Maybe I was too terse (I was on my mobile). I think I found another way to state what I wanted to get across: Writing `new Bar with FooTrait` is similar to writing `class Baz extends Bar with FooTrait` & `new Baz`; If I understood your answer correctly, this shouldn't compile, as the superclass hierarchy must be linear (`Baz extends Bar`;  `Bar extends AnyRef`) and thus can't include `Foo`. Only the `extends` clause affects linear supertypes.

Comment: no, not only `extends` but also `with` do affect supertypes, e.g. `class Baz extends FooTrait with BarTrait` leads to "error: illegal inheritance" , cuz Bar and Foo are conflicting supertypes.

Comment: @SillyFreak I think you got the point. And just to be clear, as @Wei-Ching Lin pointed out, the problem only occurs with the `extends` part, But the `extends` can come into play even when you are just doing `new Bar with FooTrait` through expansion. But I think that's what you meant.